# Looking for alternatives of Crystal Report C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I`ve been using Crystal Reports like 4 months,but frequently i face bugs and errors, theres a good alternative for Reports  to C#  winforms?

I have found some alternatives:

- SQL Server Reporting Services
- XtraReport Devexpress
- Yurbi
- Tableau

Which do you prefer? or which one have you found more info for troubleshooting?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [ReportViewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251771(v=vs.120).aspx) WinForms control with SSRS for some basic reports. If your data source is SQL Server then it's pretty easy to build the report with the SQL Server tools and convert it for use with the ReportViewer component ([MS conversion info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252109(v=vs.120).aspx)). Another plus is that it's free.

Honestly, so much depends on what you're looking to do reporting-wise. My usage was relatively simple so this combo worked for me.